# Get list of all child contract addresses from contract factory in solidity

Tags: solidity, encoding

I have a factory contract with the below code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: no-license
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface ChildInterface {
    function getStateVariable() external returns(uint);
}

contract Child is ChildInterface{
    uint public x;
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _owner, uint _x) {
        x = _x;
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function getStateVariable() public view returns(uint){
        return x;
    }
}

contract Parent {

 Child[] public childContracts;

 function createContract(uint seller) public {
        // - create a new Lottery instance with msg.sender as seller.
        Child newContract = new Child(msg.sender, seller);

        // - push the newly created contract to lotteries array.
        childContracts.push(newContract);
 }

function getValidChildContractAddresses() public returns(bytes memory addresses){
     Child[] memory validChildContracts;
     
     for(uint i = 0;i <= childContracts.length;i++){
         if(ChildInterface(childContracts[i]).getStateVariable() == 10){
              validChildContracts[i] = address(childContracts[i]);
         }          
     }

     addresses = abi.encode(validChildContracts);
 }
}
```

I am trying to get all the addreses of the child contracts are stored in the `childContracts` that matches a condition and convert them as bytes to be returned in the `getCreatedContractAddresses()` function.

I'm getting the error: 'TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract Child.' in this line: `validChildContracts[i] = address(childContracts[i]);`.

May I know how to achieve that?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you facing any errors? If so, can you post them?

Comment: Hi, I updated the code with error and a full code to be run on remix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the following line

`Child[] memory validChildContracts;`

This created the variable `validChildContracts` of type `Child[]`. However, it needs to be of type `address[]` as we aren't creating an instance of the child, but merely storing its' address.

`address[] memory validChildContracts;` should fix the error.

Comment: Hi, I actually need to have the `Child[]` in validChildContracts so that I can use it to change state varialbe by calling methods with in the child contract like: `ChildInterface(validChildContracts[i]).childContractMethod()`. Is it possible even If I use it as `address[] memory validChildContracts`?

Comment: I am trying to use this functionality with chainlink's `checkupkeep` and `performupkeep` functions.  like passing the `validChildContracts` list of addreses to the `performupkeep` function and call `ChildInterface(validChildContracts[i]).somefunctionInChildContract()`. May I know if that will make changes to the state variables deployed contract under the `validChildContracts[i]` address (where i  is a local variable in for loop)?

Comment: What you explained in `ChildInterface(validChildContracts[i]).childContractMethod()` is right. Its creating an instance of `ChildItnterface` at the address `validChildContracts[i]`. You can then interact with it normally.

Comment: hi @pbsh, I am getting the following error when I try running `getValidChildContractAddresses()` in Parent contract: `Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.`

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from `getValidChildContractAddresses` because there isn't any code inside it that's sending ether?

Comment: Yes, it is. try running the code on remix. I read [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/94471/90888), It might not always be the payable issue it is kind of like a misleading error from remix.